# Calculating wall area facing outdoors from a building shapefile QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, area

I have a building shapefile (polygons) with the height of the buildings. Is there a way for estimating the wall area facing outdoors of a building? Note that I must differentiate the outdoor area from the interior area (the interior faces of contiguous polygons)
Update: I use QGIS and building height is uniform per building and is an attribute

Comment: Sure, there's many ways, but first you need to choose the GIS/CAD tool you want to use, and give it a try.  Broad, open-ended questions don't tend to generate good answers, so we ask that you focus them on a solution framework and attempt.

Comment: I am so sorry, I forgot. I use QGIS.

Comment: Is the height of the walls for one building uniform? Is the height stored as an attribute?

Comment: Yes, the height is uniform and it is stored as an attribute.